# Weird issue with PHP's DateTime::add not adding time

Tags: php, datetime

I've managed to reduce this to a small script which reproduces the issue (Tried on two different PC's, but both with 5.3.6):

```
<?php
$item = array('monthly_on_the' => 4);
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('first day of this month');
print_r($date);
$interval = new DateInterval('P'.$item['monthly_on_the'].'D');
print_r($interval);
$return = $date->add($interval);
if (!$return) die('Bad stuff happened!');
print_r($date);
```

---

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2012-02-01 17:15:23
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Australia/Sydney
)
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 4
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2012-02-01 17:15:23
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Australia/Sydney
)
```

Is this a bug and if so, has it been fixed in more recent versions of PHP? Or is there something weird in the time stuff that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Looks like a bug - works for me in 5.3.9 though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's a bug. I'm experiencing the same thing with PHP 5.3.6. Apparently it's fixed in 5.3.7. See the changelog:

http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.7

Bug Report:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54340

Workaround (if you can't upgrade):

```
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('first day of this month', $date->getTimestamp()));
```

Comment: Cheers, I was trying to find a mention of it in their bugtracker, but not finding anything. Good to see it was fixed.